# In an array list, new variable gets added and as well as replaces the existing values with new one

Tags: java, android, arraylist

In an array list, when new variables are added using

```
 pointList.add(i , coord);
```

the new variable gets added and as well as replaces the existing values with new one.
how to stop these replacing variables ?

```
for(int i=0;i<coordinateArray.length();i++)
        {
            brokenArray= coordinateArray.getJSONObject(i);  
            x=brokenArray.getInt("x");
            y=brokenArray.getInt("y");

            Log.d("x", " "+i+ " "+x );
            Log.d("y", " "+i+ " "+y );

            coord.set(x, y);
            pointList.add(i , coord);

            Log.d("pointList", pointList.toString());
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the bug.

```
 coord.set(x, y);
```

You are setting the value in the loop to the same object.

Create the coord object inside the loop and add it.

```
for(int i=0;i<coordinateArray.length();i++)
    {
        brokenArray= coordinateArray.getJSONObject(i);  
        x=brokenArray.getInt("x");
        y=brokenArray.getInt("y");

        Log.d("x", " "+i+ " "+x );
        Log.d("y", " "+i+ " "+y );
        Coordinate coord = new Coordinate ();
        coord.set(x, y);

        pointList.add(i , coord);

        Log.d("pointList", pointList.toString());
    }
```

Comment: yes, jeet you setting the single object at different -different index. Every time you set XY it get replace in same obejct

Comment: @jeet.chanchawat i did not get what you are saying.

Answer (score 6):

Based on the code you've provided, you're using `coord.set(x, y)` on the same object every time.  Adding an object to a `List` *does not make a copy of it*.

Java passes references by value, not objects by value; when you call `pointList.add(i, coord)`, you are adding a reference to the `coord` object to the list, not a new copy of the `coord` object.

Instead, you *must* create a new `Point` or `Coordinates` or whatever object each time through the loop.  You cannot reuse the `coord` object the way you're doing it here.

Comment: "Java passes references by value, not objects by value" thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

this solved problem :)

```
 for(int i=0;i<coordinateArray.length();i++)
        {
            brokenArray= coordinateArray.getJSONObject(i);  
            x=brokenArray.getInt("x");
            y=brokenArray.getInt("y");

            Log.d("x", " "+i+ " "+x );
            Log.d("y", " "+i+ " "+y );
            Point coord = new Point();
            coord.set(x, y);
            pointList.add(i , coord);
            coord=null;
            Log.d("pointList", pointList.toString());
        }
```